# Visual Studio 2022 Project dependencies NuGetPackages won't load

Tags: visual-studio, dependencies, nuget-package

[image]

Everything was working until I cleaned one project and then the NuGetPackages won't load.
I've tried to clean the solution and all projects. I've also tried to build, rebuild, unload, load the projects. Then I removed .vs folder and restarted VS but noting worked. Then I repaired VS and still nothing worked.

I'm using VS 2022 17.0.0 Preview 4.1

Answer (score 5):

Check that your package sources are setup correctly.  I noticed that after installing VS 2022 RC3 (maybe before that, but didn't notice until today) that my package sources had all been deleted.

1. Tools->Options
2. Nuget Package Manger->Package Sources
3. Check for a source that points to:
   https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

If its not there, add one by clicking the "+" button near top right.
Then update the "Name" and "Source" fields at the bottom, then click the "Update" button in the bottom right.

[Screen Shot of Package Sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a95v2.png)